# Error in is.pbalanced.default(x) : argument "y" is missing, with no default, due to stata imported labels

Tags: r, plm

For the following panel data set:

```
panel <- structure(list(uurwerk = structure(c(40, 40, 40, 40, 36, 1, 32, 
36, 32, 32, 36, 36, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 38, 38, 38, 38, 60, 55, 
40, 42, 42, 42), label = "hours/week work in fact (on average)", class = c("labelled", 
"numeric")), loon_c = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "pay/salary [gross] mean int", class = c("labelled", 
"numeric")), mtr_loon = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.4195, 0.42, 0, 0.404, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), label = "pay/salary [gross] mean int", class = c("labelled", 
"numeric")), ntot = structure(c(33084.2085, 31810.0215, 21653.7235, 
21961.9788, 21535.29225, 24139.039, 22988.2945, 22183.3175, 84427.88258, 
21729.72304, 24248.3388, 23044.16914, 24783.0759660205, 24955.49, 
26060.0875, 29328.0404, 30407.6135, 39047.7663137553, 24467.7521372549, 
37826.93, 25963.83683, 24516.76866, 24941.179175, 27549.5975, 
32690.0255, 25200.10125, 23777.335), label = "total net income", class = c("labelled", 
"numeric")), INC = structure(c(6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("[    0,   3010)", "[ 3010,  20300)", 
"[20300,  27189)", "[27189,  34020)", "[34020,  40767)", "[40767,  50961)", 
"[50961,1165420]"), class = c("labelled", "factor"), label = "total netto income household 2013"), 
    year = structure(c(1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L), .Label = c("2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", 
    "2016", "2017", "2018"), class = "factor"), nohhold = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("6", 
    "21", "38", "106", "116", "175", "262"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("6-2011", 
"6-2012", "6-2015", "6-2016", "38-2011", "38-2012", "38-2013", 
"38-2014", "38-2015", "38-2016", "38-2017", "38-2018", "106-2011", 
"106-2014", "106-2015", "106-2016", "106-2017", "116-2011", "116-2013", 
"116-2014", "116-2016", "175-2015", "175-2018", "262-2011", "262-2012", 
"262-2013", "262-2014"), class = c("pdata.frame", "data.frame"
), index = structure(list(nohhold = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("6", "38", "106", "116", 
"175", "262"), class = "factor"), year = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("2011", "2012", 
"2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 5L, 6L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 33L, 35L, 36L, 38L, 43L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L
), class = c("pindex", "data.frame")))
```

I would like to run a(ny) random effects model:

```
library(plm)
summary(plm(uurwerk ~ loon_c + ntot, model="random", data=panel))
```

But I get the error:

```
Error in is.pbalanced.default(x) : argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how this can be the case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: when I try to reproduce your example, I have : `Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) :   cannot coerce class ‘c("pseries", "labelled", "haven_labelled")’ to a data.frame`

Comment: That is weird, it works even without loading the libraries `foreign` and `haven` (labels) for me. I will see if I can remove the labels from the `dput`.

Comment: @bretauv Would you mind trying again? I removed the variables which have the class `"haven_labelled"`.

Comment: Okay I have your error now

Comment: Apparently, the error appears because your data is unbalanced. If you replace `data = panel` by `data = make.pbalanced(panel)`, it works. However, I don't know why this error appears as I thought that random effects could be used on unbalanced panel data. I can't help you more with that

Comment: @bretauv Thanks for giving it a try. I am surprised you got it to work. For me it still gives the same error. And it should indeed work with unbalanced panels: It works properly with a different unbalanced panel I have.

Comment: Also possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61253996/2554330

Comment: It was a bug in package plm, fixed in version 2.4-4. The root cause is slightly different to what has been analysed here, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is coming from your dependent variable:

```
class(panel$uurwerk)
[1] "pseries"  "labelled" "numeric"
```

From your formula I guess you are treating it as continuous, so you can do:

```
plm(as.numeric(uurwerk) ~ loon_c + ntot, model="random",data=panel)

Model Formula: as.numeric(uurwerk) ~ loon_c + ntot

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      loon_c        ntot 
 4.0427e+01 -9.8477e-02 -9.2704e-06
```

Comment: That works.. Although I am a bit surprised by the reason. The class and mode of the variable are both numeric.. How is it possible I still need to specify it? Any idea? In any case, thank you for solving this for me!

Comment: Yes, it is numeric, but the pseries class precedes it. Depends on how the underlying function detects or checks your dependent variable..

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify how you created the data set? Why does it have `"labelled"` as a class?

Comment: @Tom? can you clarify with @Helix123

Comment: @Helix123 It's a Stata (.dta) import using the Stata variable labels from the .dta file

Comment: How do you import? Via package `haven` in current version?

Comment: It was a bug in package plm, fixed in version 2.4-4. The root cause is slightly different to what has been analysed here, though.