# Error when estimating random effects model with plm package when haven is loaded

Tags: r, plm, r-haven

I have a weird problem when estimating a random effects with the `plm` package in R.

Here is a link to a `dput` of part of my data: [https://pastebin.com/raw/mTdh26dg](https://pastebin.com/raw/CCL3Pabm)

My code is:

```
library(plm)
library(haven)
pmales <- pdata.frame(males_part, index = c("NR", "YEAR"))
random <- plm(WAGE ~ SCHOOL + EXPER + EXPER2 + BLACK + HISP + MAR + UNION + RUR + NE + NC + S + factor(YEAR), 
              data = pmales, model = "random")
```

The reason I included `libary(haven)` is that my original data set is a .dta file.

When I run this code I get this error:

```
Error in is.pbalanced.default(x) : 
  argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

The weird thing is that if I start with a clean R session and don't load `haven` (and the import the data from the `dput`), I don't get this error. I do get the error if I import from the `dput` but load `haven` anyway. I also don't get the error when estimating `within` or `pooling` models (even with haven `loaded`).

Here is my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 19.3

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=nl_NL.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=nl_NL.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=nl_NL.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] haven_2.2.0 plm_2.2-3  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6     rstudioapi_0.11  Formula_1.2-3    magrittr_1.5     hms_0.5.3        MASS_7.3-51.5    lattice_0.20-41  rlang_0.4.5     
 [9] bibtex_0.4.2.2   fansi_0.4.1      stringr_1.4.0    tools_3.6.3      grid_3.6.3       nlme_3.1-144     cli_2.0.2        ellipsis_0.3.0  
[17] maxLik_1.3-8     miscTools_0.6-26 assertthat_0.2.1 lmtest_0.9-37    digest_0.6.25    lifecycle_0.2.0  tibble_3.0.0     crayon_1.3.4    
[25] bdsmatrix_1.3-4  vctrs_0.2.4      Rdpack_0.11-1    gbRd_0.4-11      glue_1.4.0       sandwich_2.5-1   stringi_1.4.6    pillar_1.4.3    
[33] compiler_3.6.3   forcats_0.5.0    pkgconfig_2.0.3  zoo_1.8-7
```

Is this a bug in `plm` or `haven`? Or some sort of incompatibility of the two (or their dependencies)?

Comment: It was a bug in package plm, fixed in version 2.4-4. The root cause is slightly different to what has been analysed here, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that your data `males_part` is a tibble, but you don't have the `tibble` package loaded until you attach `haven`.  If you don't have `tibble` loaded, then you won't have any methods for the tibble classes `"tbl_df"` and `"tbl"`, and it will act exactly like a data frame.  Once `tibble` is loaded, it will start to act like a tibble.

This is an issue because tibbles and data frames aren't identical, but the class of a tibble includes `"data.frame"`.  I'd guess what's happening is that `plm` assumes that extracting a single column from a data frame gives a vector, but with a tibble, it gives another tibble.

The workaround for you is pretty simple.  Just use `males_part <- as.data.frame(males_part)` to remove the tibble class, and then `haven` won't matter.

Conceivably this is worth reporting to the maintainer of `plm`.  It's a design flaw in `tibble` that is causing the problem (if tibbles inherit from `data.frame`, they should act like data frames), but tibbles are pretty common nowadays, and that design is unlikely to change.  The `plm` function could protect itself against this by putting `data <- as.data.frame(data)` early in the `pdata.frame` function,
or protecting every column extraction with `drop = TRUE`.

Comment: This does solve the issue, thanks! But doesn't the `haven` package load the `tibble` package?

Comment: One other thing. This is for a class assignment and only some of us get this error. We all have recent (3.6.x) R versions and different operating systems and the latest versions of these packages.

Comment: Yes, `haven` loads `tibble`, and that triggers the bug.  Not sure what's different about your classmates.  Maybe they never turned the data into a tibble, e.g. if you use `read.csv` you get a data frame, if you use `readr::read_csv` you get a tibble.

Comment: I added some text to the first paragraph to explain what's going on in more detail.

Comment: Thank you, I have accepted your answer. This is such a weirdly specific bug, especially since it doesn't happen when estimating other models

Comment: I'd guess most packages know about this by now and have protected themselves against tibble issues.

Comment: I have sent an email to the maintainer of plm, Yves Croissant. I assume it will be fixed soon.

Comment: This seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60847460/error-in-is-pbalanced-defaultx-argument-y-is-missing-with-no-default-due/60848941#60848941

Comment: It was a bug in package plm, fixed in version 2.4-4. The root cause is slightly different to what has been analysed here, though.